# Installer overhead of wix, InnoSetup, nsis

Tags: installation, wix, inno-setup, nsis

What is typical package size overhead of installer created by Wix?

Same question about NSIS and InnoSetup.

Comment: You'd have to define overhead.  Do you mean package size, execution time or something else?

Comment: Package size. Added that to question.

Answer (score 3):

NSIS installer has an overhead of only 34 KB.

Inno Setup smallest size is about 350kB (ten times more than NSIS).

Comment: You'd have to define how to measure to give an honest answer. For example do you add up the size of the files ( compressed or uncompressed) when comparing to the size the package. For that matter, a self extracting zip probably has the least overhead but that doesn't mean it's the most robust solution.   That said an empty WiX MSI with no UI is 24KB.  Add in the standard "WixUI_Mondo" UI package and the size is 224KB.

Comment: Thank you. That about answers my question.